# Android Dark Mode: Elevation Not Changing Surface Color

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I'm following google's excellent [blog post](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties) to make a dark theme for my app, but I don't see any reference on how I get the elevation effects on my views(buttons, app bar, etc) to work. For example when I set my app theme to 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">` 
and make a button or a card like so:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/keypadOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/surface"
        android:elevation="01dp"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textColor="@color/onSurface"
        android:textSize="36sp" />
```

I would expect to see the effect that makes the object appear lighter due to the semi-transparent white overlay used in dark themes to imply elevation or being closer to a light source than the background. Instead, my buttons,action bar, etc, are the same color as the background and therefore invisible.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to implement this elevation functionality manually or is that provided by the Material library?
2. If I get this working automatically for Android 10+ will I have to implement a manual solution for backwards compatibility on versions 9 and earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the [solution](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/issues/150). In order to achieve the overlay tinting effect on elevation for CardViews you have to use the Material lib's special object that contains this functionality: MaterialCardView. Once you use this CardView, set it's
`app:cardElevation` attribute to change the white overlay mentioned in the google blog post on Dark Mode I linked above.

For example, my CardView looks like this now:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
android:id="@+id/testCard" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:elevation="18dp" app:cardCornerRadius="4dp" />
```

Note that this special elevation attribute is only available for MaterialCardViews, despite other views like Toolbars having a Material version.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your using material components library theme and `DayNight` variant like this

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

this should automatically change surface color for `AppBarLayout`, `Toolbar` and `MaterialCardView` but if you want to set this auto surface color change based on elevation for others view set your

`android:background="?attr/colorSurface"` or in case of `MaterialCardView` use this `app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSurface"` and apply elevation with

`android:elevation="4dp"` or in some cases without android namespace `elevation="4dp"` or in case of `MaterialCardView` use this `app:cardElevation="4dp"`