# Android: No CardView elevation on dark theme

Tags: android, android-cardview, shadow, elevation

I'm working on a dark theme for my app, and everything's working fine, except for the CardView that completely loses its elevation after setting dark mode.

My CardView:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cvTestType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTestType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

App Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

This is how CardView looks with normal light theme:

[image: CardView Light]

As you can see, not only CardView, but also ActionBar both shows elevation correctly.

This is how screen looks like in dark mode:

[image: CardView Dark]

Here CardView and ActionBar, both loose elevation effect completely.

I've tried the suggestions in this: [android-dark-mode-elevation-not-changing-surface-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860240/android-dark-mode-elevation-not-changing-surface-color)

and this: https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/issues/150

and others to no avail.

What can I try next?